# Calculate children values without taking into account grandchildren in a hiearchy

Tags: mdx

I've got a hierarchy setup in my OLAP-cube and I would like to calculate the child values from a specific node without taking into account the childrens children.

```
SELECT 
    [Colset]
   ,[RowSet] ON 1
  FROM [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089].Children
```

If I execute this query I get sum for every child throughout the hierarchy. (Which of course is want you want in 99% of the cases). I instead would like to get the childrens values *without* the grandchildren.

What I like to do is something like this (pseudo-code)

```
SELECT 
    [Colset]
   ,[RowSet] ON 1
  FROM Except( [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089].Children, [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089].GrandChildren)
```

Is this possible, and if, how?

Comment: Are you saying that the children values are NOT the aggregation of the grand-children values ?

Comment: They are the aggregation, i want them WITHOUT aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SUM aggregation for your measure, something like that should do it:

```
with member val as sum( [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089], [Measures].currentMember )
    - sum( descendants( [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089], 1, SELF ), [Measures].currentMember )

select ... where val
```

Comment: I need slice the data. I tried your solution and it almost worked though. WHERE DESCENDANTS( [Hierarchy].[Tree].&[24089], 1, SELF) returns the correct values if the child node in turn dont have more childs.

For example
- TOP
-- A
--- AA
-- B

B will show the correct value, A will be "nothing".